# What is the difference between the GeoIP2 MaxMind pom and my local one?

Tags: java, maven, geoip

I'm  following this guide:

https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java

It says:

> We recommend installing this package with Maven. To do this, add the dependency to your pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

There is also *pom.xml* file in the Git repository of GeoIP2 which is much longer - what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cited from the [official homepage](https://maven.apache.org/):

> Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool. Based on the concept of a project object model (POM), Maven can manage a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of information.

Think of the *pom.xml* as the heart of Maven. In the file you can specify dependencies (most typically *jar* files), and other information, such as how the project should be built. Without digging to deep into this, one of Maven's strengths is that it manages the *dependencies* of projects.

To answer your concrete question, GeoIP2 manages its dependencies using Maven. This section of its pom.xml defines them:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.maxmind.db</groupId>
        <artifactId>maxmind-db</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

By using Maven in your own project, you will only need to add the one dependency to GeoIP2. Maven will then search for the dependency in a *repository*, typically the *[Maven Central Repository](http://central.sonatype.org/)* if Maven isn't configured to use another. It will also automatically download all other needed dependencies ([transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)), in this case it would be the dependencies listed above, plus any other dependencies those in turn depend on, and so on.

So, a short recap: Without a dependency management tool like Maven, you would need to manually make sure you have all the correct dependencies on the classpath. Maven fixes this for you.